# Please explain which Eclipse builders are actually needed and how to fix slow blocking builders

Tags: eclipse

I have a few Builders in my .project files some which seem to block while doing "stuff" which if i cancel does not affect my ability to run tests etc as the class files themselves have already been created and placed in the output dir.

- I seem to get a lot of "analyzing API" which is probably connected to OSGI.
- I also seem to get a lot of waiting while it does stuff with some xml schemas embedded inside 3rd party jars. If i cancel this builder it makes no difference everything still works...Im confused...

  ```
  <buildSpec>
  <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
      <arguments>
      </arguments>
  </buildCommand>
  <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder</name>
      <arguments>
      </arguments>
  </buildCommand>
  <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder</name>
      <arguments>
      </arguments>
  </buildCommand>
  <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.apiAnalysisBuilder</name>
      <arguments>
      </arguments>
  </buildCommand>
  ```

Is there anywhere on the web that lists what each builder does, and how to better use it, rather than just letting them run and show errors and stuff.

Comment: Can you please attach your .project file, so we can have a look at the exact set of builders and natures?

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to "API Analysis Builder", this comes from PDE. Select your project in Package explorer, right click > Properties - look for 'Builders' and check that this builder is there.

This builder just verifies things, the compilation of your Java code is done by the 'Java Builder' which is a separate entity and comes from JDT. Hence things work, as the compiled classes are already available by the time "API Analysis Builder" is invoked.

Having said that, the builder should not 'block'. It may take a bit of time, but it should not block. If it is blocking then you can try to debug by following the instructions on http://thecoderlounge.blogspot.com/2011/04/debugging-eclipse-builders.html

EDIT: To answer what each builder does

- API Analysis Builder - See Preferences > Plugin development > API errors and Warnings and API Baselines. All these options control the behavior of this builder. Among other things this builder reports API compatibility issues, and helps you with version management of your plugins (@since tags). Also, after the Java builder this builder takes most amount of time especially if you have defined an API baseline (I have debugged this builder in the past using the instructions mentioned above)
- Manifest and Schema builders - See Preferences > Plugin development > Compilers. These options control these 2 builders. I think schema builder will verify the plugin.xml and report any issues with it and similarly Manifest builder verifies manifest.mf. I am pretty sure that these two builders do not take much time to do their jobs.

Now do you need these builders ? None of these 3 builders are mandatory to execute your code. However I think Manifest and Schema builders should be there, because otherwise you will see errors at runtime as opposed to compile time. If you want to speed up your build process inside Eclipse you can disable API analysis builder (I do at sometimes), the errors/warnings from this builder do not have anything to do with program behavior as such. This builder tries to ensure that you are a 'good' API producer and API consumer.

Comment: Yes some builders by their very name are obvious, such as JavaBuilder, but what exactly does SchemaBuilder do other than validating xml files against schemas. The strange thing SB gobbles a lot of cpu time and yet i have almost no xml files in my source...

Comment: Im interested in the reasoning and an understanding of what each builder does and why i should enable it. I am having a hard time finding stuff on Schemabuilder and how to use it more effectively.

Comment: I doubt that SchemaBuilder takes a much time. Nevertheless, do you have some data to back your claim ?

Comment: I have added a few more details to the answer, hope that will help.